# triangle pattern centered

Tags: geometry

i want to create a pattern in c++ that looks like a trianlge(or half a diamond)
using asteriscks: the pattern should have 1, 2, 3, 4, and end in 5 stars like this

```
  *
  **
 ***
 ****
*****
```

(but straight!)
my code is as follows:

-`#include 
using namespace std;
int main()
{

```
int size;
cout<<"size:"<<endl;
cin>>size;

int blank=size/2;
int newsize=1;
for (int i=0; i<=size/2; i++)
{
    for(int j=blank;j>0;j--)
        cout <<" ";
    blank--;
    for(int j=newsize; j>0; j--)
        cout <<"*";
    newsize+=2;
    cout <<endl;
}


return 0;
```

}
`
my only problem with it is that it displays 1, 3,and 5 stars like this.

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

its just a minor problem but although i have changed different parts of the code
i dont seem to get it right.

any suggestions?

thanks 
:)

Comment: by straight i mean aligned, i just couldnt fix the triangle to look like that

Comment: Do you mean aligned to right? You can't align it to be a pyramid with 1,2,3 but yes with 1,3,5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "but straight", so I'll just ignore that for now...

Start with `blank` the same value as `size`, so that you can decrement the value each time without having to decrement by a half:

```
int blank=size;
```

Loop up to `size` instead of `size/2` to get more lines:

```
for (int i=0; i<=size; i++)
```

Decrement by two in the loop for spaces to get half the number of spaces:

```
for(int j=blank;j>0;j-=2)
```

Increase the size by one instead of two to get the slower increase:

```
newsize++;
```

That should produce the output that you showed.

#### Edit:

I tested this to be sure, and the output is:

```
   *
  **
  ***
 ****
 *****
******
```

To get the exact output that you asked for, start with blank one less:

```
int blank=size - 1;
```

Comment: actually this gave me another pattern :O

Answer (score 0):

Did I get it right: you want to place some asterisks on borders of character places? If so, it isn't possible. Every asterisk (or any other symbol), when displayed in monospace fonts, will reside in a middle of a character place, like in a grid. You *can* place asterisks inside the cells, but you *cannot* place asterisks on the borders of the grid.

Comment: no i just want to make the triangle pattern; it is possible, i just cant get it exactly correct

Comment: uhm, could you please draw the pattern, to make it possible to understand what you want exactly?

Comment: the pattern is the first triangle :)

Comment: huh, I thought you want to align the first pattern to look really *straight* :)

Comment: sorry, i meant aligned because it doesnt look like a triangle :)  but my only problem is the number of stars shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
int NUMLINES = 5;

void display(int, char);

void main(){
for (int i=1; i<= NUMLINES; ++i){
    display((NUMLINES + 1 - i), ' ');
    display(( 2 * i - 1 ), '*');
    cout << endl;
}

}
void display (int howmany, char symbol){
for (int i = 1; i<=howmany; ++i)
 cout << symbol;
}
```